# What to do if /dev/md1 is full?

Tags: partitioning, apache2, mysql, swap, disk-usage

I have a dedicated server, running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS.

I have a problem with space in disk:

```
df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   7.8G  8.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  1.6G  568K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/md1               4.0G  4.0G     0 100% /
none                   4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /run/shm
none                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr   104G  1.8G   98G   2% /usr
overflow               500M     0  500M   0% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-var   709G  125G  556G  19% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home   69G   24G   43G  36% /home
```

- What can I do for free space and/or add space in `/dev/md1` or it is normal?
- I have installed `apache2`, `mysql` (I change `buffer_size`, add size to `/tmp` for queries), `memcached`, `pagespee`.
- I added a 20GB swap file:

  ```
  Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
  /dev/sda2                               partition       2097148  0       -1
  /dev/sdb2                               partition       2097148  0       -2
  /home/archivo-swap                      file            20971516 0       -3
  ```
- Can there be a problem with the usage of swap, because I change my `my.conf` of mysql, I put `innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G`?

**Ouput** of `fdisk -l`

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x4d10fd7b

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048     8390655     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         8390656    12584959     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb3        12584960  1953525167   970470104   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0b43aed6

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048     8390655     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         8390656    12584959     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3        12584960  1953525167   970470104   fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/md1: 4294 MB, 4294901760 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1048560 cylinders, total 8388480 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md3: 993.8 GB, 993761296384 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 242617504 cylinders, total 1940940032 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md3 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr: 112.7 GB, 112742891520 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13706 cylinders, total 220200960 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 773.1 GB, 773094113280 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 93990 cylinders, total 1509949440 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 75.2 GB, 75161927680 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 9137 cylinders, total 146800640 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Command `sudo du -hsx /*`

```
sudo du -hsx /*
9.8M    /bin
141M    /boot
8.0K    /dev
7.7M    /etc
24G     /home
0       /initrd.img
0       /initrd.img.old
939M    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
48K     /lost+found
8.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
14M     /node_modules
4.0K    /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/28275/task/28275/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28275/task/28275/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28275/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/28275/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       /proc
2.9G    /root
564K    /run
11M     /sbin
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
0       /tmp
1.7G    /usr
125G    /var
0       /vmlinuz
0       /vmlinuz.old
```

Information about /root
command `du -h --max-depth=1`  path ´/root´

```
4.0K    ./tmp
12K     ./.config
8.0K    ./.ssh
16K     ./.aptitude
2.8G    ./.forever
4.0K    ./.cache
31M     ./.npm
2.9G    .
```

What can I do with `./.forever` and ´./.npm´?

Comment: Well md1 *is* quite small (~4G) however you have separate /usr, /var, and /home filesystems. That only leaves things like /boot, /etc, /bin, /lib which typically are not large - but have you run something like `sudo du -hsx /*` to check? That would be my start point.

Comment: I run that command and get the information that it is up, but if i don't have access dorectly to the server how can I separate /var, /usr, /bin,/etc...?

Comment: The first thing that jumps out is you have 2.9G in /root - this is essentially root's personal home dir, there should be nothing in there unless you put it there - check you don't have any old downloads / backups lurking there

Comment: I found that ´/root´ have  `./.forever` that occupied 2.9GB and `./.npm`  that occupied 31MB, what can I do for move or solve this, I don't want to remove because I need forever for run a scrips

Comment: What is their purpose? I suggest finding a different place to keep them - either your primary user's home dir or somewhere like /usr/local. You shouldn't be logging in as root directly anyway.

Comment: Sorry for my no experience in the case, and sorry for the question, but how I move that? I'm new in this, but I try to do my best.
I need to remove, and install in user that it is not root?

Answer (score 3):

I have found a solution with help from "**steeldriver**"

**Problem**: My problem was that i run `forever start myscript.js` with user root, `forever` save all logs in folder of the user that run the script, that is why i have no space in `/dev/md1`

**Solution**: move all files that was in `/root/.forever` to my new user, `/home/user/.forever` and run `forever start myscript.js` with my new user.

I have more space in `/dev/md1`

```
df -h
Filesystem             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   7.8G  8.0K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs                  1.6G  560K  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/md1               4.0G  1.2G  2.8G  30% /
none                   4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none                   5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                   7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /run/shm
none                   100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mapper/vg00-usr   104G  1.8G   98G   2% /usr
overflow               500M     0  500M   0% /tmp
/dev/mapper/vg00-var   709G  125G  556G  19% /var
/dev/mapper/vg00-home   69G   27G   40G  41% /home
```

Folder of `root`

```
ls -ahl
total 104K
drwx------   8 root root 4.0K Jul 12 01:23 .
drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 4.0K Jul  9 00:57 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 Jul 12 00:33 all
drwx------   2 root root 4.0K Jun 27 13:02 .aptitude
-rw-------   1 root root  39K Jul 12 01:25 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 3.1K Feb 20  2014 .bashrc
drwx------   2 root root 4.0K Mar  4  2014 .cache
drwx------   3 root root 4.0K Jun 30 02:49 .config
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   29 Jun 27 13:07 created
-rw-r--r--   1 root root    0 Jul 11 21:16 findjs
-rw-------   1 root root   35 Apr 22  2015 .lesshst
-rw-------   1 root root 3.9K Jul  8 23:39 .mysql_history
-rw-------   1 root root  570 Jul 12 01:23 .nano_history
drwxr-xr-x 164 root root  12K Jul  1 21:26 .npm
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  140 Feb 20  2014 .profile
drwx------   2 root root 4.0K Jun 30 04:39 .ssh
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Jul  1 21:26 tmp
```

update 29/08/2017:

- check old kernel, remove them to get space...
- check logs file to see or clean them.

Comment: Good job! glad you fixed it