# Plesk recommends to check df -h / and is 100% used - how to free up or increase size

Tags: server, partitioning, apache2, swap, disk-usage

Plesk recommends to check df -h /

```
[root@s20284804 ~]# df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1        4.0G  4.0G   22M 100% /


[root@s20284804 ~]# du -hsx /*
7.2M    /bin
55M /boot
4.0K    /cgroup
1.8M    /composer.phar
264K    /composer-setup.php
212K    /dev
4.0K    /domains.txt
32M /etc
88K /home
317M    /lib
23M /lib64
48K /lost+found
4.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
2.6G    /opt
du: cannot access `/proc/20669/task/20669/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/20669/task/20669/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/20669/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/20669/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0   /proc
8.0K    /README.md
871M    /root
14M /sbin
4.0K    /selinux
4.0K    /srv
0   /sys
16K /tmp
3.1G    /usr
41G /var



fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc6b58f8a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1         523     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb2             523         784     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sdb3             784      182402  1458846104   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/sda: 1500.3 GB, 1500301910016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 182401 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x49d63b46

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1         523     4194304   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda2             523         784     2097152   82  Linux swap / Solaris
Partition 2 does not end on cylinder boundary.
/dev/sda3             784      182402  1458846104   fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 3 does not end on cylinder boundary.

Disk /dev/md3: 1493.9 GB, 1493858320384 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 364711504 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/md1: 4294 MB, 4294901760 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 1048560 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-usr: 5368 MB, 5368709120 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 652 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-var: 107.4 GB, 107374182400 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 13054 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg00-home: 5368 MB, 5368709120 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 652 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

I don't know how i could free this up or increase it. Any advice?

Comment: 4 GB is way to little space for /. You will need at least 12 GB and preferably 20 or more.You will have to reinstall and choose a better partitioning.

Comment: Thank you for responding. This is an issue from the previous dev who installed it. are there methods to increase it? @SorenA

Comment: The best method of increasing size is determined by system itself, the easiest is to ensure you have backups, boot 'live' system (so / is not in use) then adjust sizes & correct for any movements (if /boot is moved; grub may not be fixed; I usually only fix this if it's a problem on next boot)).

Comment: @guiverc. I found this https://askubuntu.com/questions/797475/what-to-do-if-dev-md1-is-full. We have similar problem, but im still finding files that takes up size

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase partition size on which Ubuntu is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116351/increase-partition-size-on-which-ubuntu-is-installed)

Comment: @user535733 I am not very good on administrator work. I have a folder on /usr/local/op/ that is large enough. I wish i could move it or mount it somewhere on my other disk which is 1T. Will it work?

Comment: @guiverc. I found mine on /usr/local. I think I can mount it to point to my other disk which is 1T. Do you think it would work and free up my root partition?